# how to check if the player make a CLICK on a Body with farseer physics?

Tags: xna, farseer

I need to know how I can check in Farseer Physics if a player/user clicks on a specific body, is this possible?

Do I have to write my own methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Mouse.GetState()` and compare the mouse state this frame with the state from the previous frame (you have to store it) to determine when and where clicks occur. This should be trivial, so I won't go into further detail (if you need it, ask an additional question specifically about XNA and not Farseer).

Once you have your mouse position as a `Vector2`, pass it to `World.TestFixture(Vector2 point)` which will return a `Fixture`. (You can also use `TestPointAll` to get a list of fixtures, if you want to handle having more than one under the cursor).

If you want a `Body`, use the `Fixture.Body` property.